# openweathermap weather tile in Leaflet in R

Tags: javascript, r, openweathermap, htmlwidgets, r-leaflet

I am trying to add custom weather tiles on a `leaflet` map in a Shiny application using `leaflet-openweathermap` javascript library available [here](https://github.com/buche/leaflet-openweathermap). I am not conversant with javascript and the map doesn't render the weather layers.

I first downloaded `leaflet-openweathermap.js` and placed it in `www/js` folder in my app's path. I then registered the plugin:

```
openWeatherPlugin <- htmlDependency(
  "Leaflet.OpenWeather",
  "1.6.0",
  src = normalizePath(path = getwd()),
  script = "www/js/leaflet.openweathermap.js"
)
```

To render a weather layer on leaflet, this is what I tried:

```
leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  registerPlugin(openWeatherPlugin) %>% 
  onRender("
            function(el, x){
            L.OWM.clouds({showLegend: true, opacity: 0.5, appId: 'MY_APP_ID'})
            }
           ")
```

`MY_APP_ID` is a valid ID obtained from openweathermap.org
However the above code doesn't generate the desired weather layer of clouds. I am not conversant with javascript and don't know what's wrong with this code. Appreciate some help please.

Comment: Can you include the code for `registerPlugin` too. I got an error that `L.Layer` is not defined from the openweather.js in line 225 (`L.Layer.extend`). It may be due to different leaflet-versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What if you add `.addTo(this);` in the `onRender` call, like:

```
  onRender("function(el, x){
          L.OWM.clouds({showLegend: true, opacity: 0.5, appId: 'MY_APP_ID'}).addTo(this);
        }
       ")
```

and the javascript file is called `leaflet-openweathermap.js` and you've got `leaflet.openweathermap.js` or did you change to hyphen to a point?

I am not getting any clouds with your API key. So I dont think the ID is valid, since I'm getting this msg in the console.

> [HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized 99ms]

The `appId` is your private key, not the name.

It works with a working key.

[image]

Comment: thanks! `addTo(this)` did the trick. I changed the hyphen to a point in the javascript file name and am using a valid `appId`.

Answer (score 4):

I am using the `addProviderTiles` function instead of raw javascript or the openweather library. For this I had to add the `apiKey` within `providerTileOptions` for my OpenWeatherMap account:

```
mw = leaflet() %>%
    addProviderTiles(providers$CartoDB.Positron) %>%
    setView(-122.36075812146, 35.6759920119894, zoom = 11) %>% 
    addProviderTiles(providers$OpenWeatherMap.Wind,  
        options=providerTileOptions(apiKey="<myAPIkey>"))              

mw
```