# external leaflet map in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, openweathermap

I'm setting up a shiny app, and want to include this map : 
https://openweathermap.org/weathermap?basemap=map&cities=true&layer=temperature&lat=47&lon=1&zoom=6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Luckily leaflet enables you to serve a rainbow of tiles. To check which are available for OpenWeatherMap, try

```
library(leaflet)
> names(providers)[grepl("OpenWeatherMap", names(providers))]
 [1] "OpenWeatherMap"                      "OpenWeatherMap.Clouds"               "OpenWeatherMap.CloudsClassic"       
 [4] "OpenWeatherMap.Precipitation"        "OpenWeatherMap.PrecipitationClassic" "OpenWeatherMap.Rain"                
 [7] "OpenWeatherMap.RainClassic"          "OpenWeatherMap.Pressure"             "OpenWeatherMap.PressureContour"     
[10] "OpenWeatherMap.Wind"                 "OpenWeatherMap.Temperature"          "OpenWeatherMap.Snow"
```

So, you could call up your temperature map. Note that you need to apply for an API key (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53137105/openweathermap-weather-tile-in-leaflet-in-r)) at the service's website.

```
leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>%
  addProviderTiles(providers$OpenWeatherMap.Temperature,
                   options = providerTileOptions(apiKey="<your_api_key_here>")) %>%
  setView(14.4220129, 46.0846989, zoom = 6)
```

Not sure how to integrate the cities layer yet, though.

[image]